# Is it possible to have a multi line footer in memoir?

Tags: header-footer, memoir

MWE:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\makepagestyle{mystyle}
\makeoddfoot{mystyle}{my journal}{\thepage}{}
\pagestyle{mystyle}

\begin{document}

Some text.

\end{document}
```

The footer is supposed to comprise of 1) the page number in the center, 2) an empty line, 3) the name of the journal on the left of a third footer line. Is this possible from within `memoir` or should I look into using some other package (`fancyhdr`?) for this? I tried to "push down" the journal name using `\\` and others, but to no avail.

EDIT: I think I'll go with Werner's solution, as it keeps the footer elements separate, however the adjusted footskip is still too small. Latex doesn't complain anymore, but using lipsum (example below) one can see that the page number is almost touching the text. I wonder now how do I best calculate the foot skip, considering also that I'm still going to change the page dimensions. I could just adjust it by trial and error, but I'd prefer to follow some formula.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\makepagestyle{mystyle}
\makeoddfoot{mystyle}{my journal}{\begin{tabular}[b]{c}
    \thepage\\ \mbox{}\\ \mbox{}
  \end{tabular}}{}
\pagestyle{mystyle}
\setlength{\footskip}{35pt}
\begin{document}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the footer in a `tabular`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\makepagestyle{mystyle}
\makeoddfoot{mystyle}{my journal}{\begin{tabular}[b]{c}
    \thepage\\ \mbox{A}\\ \mbox{B}
  \end{tabular}}{}
\pagestyle{mystyle}
\setlength{\footskip}{35pt}
\begin{document}

Some text.

\end{document}
```

Remove the `A` and `B` - it's just for showing the vertical alignment.

Due to the enlarged footer, you need to adjust `\footskip` as well - you'll see a warning in the `.log` to that effect if you don't.

Answer (score 4):

Sure. You can use a `\parbox`, something like

```
\makeoddfoot{mystyle}{}{\parbox{\textwidth}{\centering\thepage\\[\baselineskip] my journal\hfill\null}}{}
```

and increase the height for the footskip using `\setheadfoot`.

The necessary value to use will be displayed in the output console and in the `.log` file. For example, with the settings I gave before, the console shows

```
Class memoir Warning: The material used in the footer is too large
(32.39996pt) for the given foot skip (25.29494pt), it is recommended to
either increase the foot skip or redesign the fotoer
(in both cases you will find help in the memoir manual). on input line 12.
```

A complete example:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\makepagestyle{mystyle}
\makeoddfoot{mystyle}{}{\parbox{\textwidth}{\centering\thepage\\[\baselineskip] my journal\hfill\null}}{}
\setheadfoot{\headheight}{32.4pt} % reverted my faulty edit
\pagestyle{mystyle}

\begin{document}

Some text.

\end{document}
```

[image]